# fatal: [10.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"msg": " [WARNING] Ansible is being run in a world writable directory Ansible

Tags: ansible

SSH Authentication problem

TASK [backup : Gather facts (ops)] *************************************************************************************

> fatal: [10.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"msg": " [WARNING] Ansible is being run
>   in a world writable directory
>   (/mnt/c/Users/AnirudhSomanchi/Desktop/KVM/Scripting/Ansible/network/backup),
>   ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source. For more information see
>   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir\n{\"socket_path\":
>   (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir/n{/'socket_path/':)
>   \"/home/SaiAnirudh/.ansible/pc/87fd82198c\", \"exception\":
>   \"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   \\"/usr/bin/ansible-connection\\", line 104, in start\n
>   self.connection._connect()\n  File
>   \\"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/network_cli.py\\",
>   line 327, in _connect\n    ssh = self.paramiko_conn._connect()\n 
>   File
>   \\"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py\\",
>   line 245, in _connect\n    self.ssh = SSH_CONNECTION_CACHE[cache_key]
>   = self._connect_uncached()\n  File \\"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py\\",
>   line 368, in _connect_uncached\n    raise
>   AnsibleConnectionFailure(msg)\nAnsibleConnectionFailure: paramiko:
>   The authenticity of host '10.X.X.X' can't be established.\nThe
>   ssh-rsa key fingerprint is 4b595d868720e28de57bef23c90546ad.\n\",
>   \"messages\": [[\"vvvv\", \"local domain socket does not exist,
>   starting it\"], [\"vvvv\", \"control socket path is
>   /home/SaiAnirudh/.ansible/pc/87fd82198c\"], [\"vvvv\", \"loaded
>   cliconf plugin for network_os vyos\"], [\"log\", \"network_os is set
>   to vyos\"], [\"vvvv\", \"\"]], \"error\": \"paramiko: The authenticity
>   of host '10.X.X.X' can't be established.\nThe ssh-rsa key fingerprint
>   is 4b595d868720e28de57bef23c90546ad.\"}"}

Command used`-- ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts --ask-vault-pass`

Tried changing 
`host_key_checking = False`  in Ansible.cfg

Command used`-- ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts --ask-vault-pass`

=====================================================================
playbook.yml

```
---
-  hosts: all
   gather_facts: false
   roles:
   - backup
```

===============================================================

Main.yml

```
C:\Ansible\network\backup\roles\backup\tasks\main.yml

- name: Gather facts (ops)
  vyos_facts: 
    gather_subset: all

- name: execute Vyos run to initiate backup
  vyos_command:
    commands: 
      -  sh configuration commands | no-more 
  register: v_backup

- name: local_action
  local_action:
   module: copy
   dest: "C:/Users/Desktop/KVM/Scripting/Ansible/network/backup/RESULTS/Backup.out"
   content: "{{ v_backup.stdout[0] }}"
```

===============================================================

Ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

===============================================================

Hosts

```
[all]
10.X.X.X

[all:vars]
ansible_user=
ansible_ssh_pass=
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_network_os=vyos
```

We need the backup of the vyatta devices but getting the following error

Vault password:

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [backup : Gather facts (ops)] *************************************************************************************

> fatal: [10.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"msg": " [WARNING] Ansible is being run
>   in a world writable directory
>   (/mnt/c/Users/AnirudhSomanchi/Desktop/KVM/Scripting/Ansible/network/backup),
>   ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source. For more information see
>   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir\n{\"socket_path\":
>   (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir/n{/'socket_path/':)
>   \"/home/SaiAnirudh/.ansible/pc/87fd82198c\", \"exception\":
>   \"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   \\"/usr/bin/ansible-connection\\", line 104, in start\n
>   self.connection._connect()\n  File
>   \\"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/network_cli.py\\",
>   line 327, in _connect\n    ssh = self.paramiko_conn._connect()\n 
>   File
>   \\"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py\\",
>   line 245, in _connect\n    self.ssh = SSH_CONNECTION_CACHE[cache_key]
>   = self._connect_uncached()\n  File \\"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py\\",
>   line 368, in _connect_uncached\n    raise
>   AnsibleConnectionFailure(msg)\nAnsibleConnectionFailure: paramiko:
>   The authenticity of host '10.X.X.X' can't be established.\nThe
>   ssh-rsa key fingerprint is 4b595d868720e28de57bef23c90546ad.\n\",
>   \"messages\": [[\"vvvv\", \"local domain socket does not exist,
>   starting it\"], [\"vvvv\", \"control socket path is
>   /home/SaiAnirudh/.ansible/pc/87fd82198c\"], [\"vvvv\", \"loaded
>   cliconf plugin for network_os vyos\"], [\"log\", \"network_os is set
>   to vyos\"], [\"vvvv\", \"\"]], \"error\": \"paramiko: The authenticity
>   of host '10.X.X.X' can't be established.\nThe ssh-rsa key fingerprint
>   is 4b595d868720e28de57bef23c90546ad.\"}"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************

> 10.X.X.X             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: Are you sure the correct ansible.cfg is getting picked up? You can run `ansible --version` in the same directory as you are running `ansible-playbook` to check

Comment: Got it once I gave the defaults in ansible.cfg file it started working. Thank you

Comment: @Sai Anirudh , can you elaborate how you solved this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[WARNING] Ansible is in a world writable directory , ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source.
```

I also got this warning but this won't lead you to the failure of your command execution in ansible. it is just a warning which means you have given full permission(i.e **drwxrwxrwx or 777**) to your directory which is not secure. you can remove this warning by changing permission with **chmod** command(like `sudo chmod 755`).

Comment: Yes, it doesn't cause failure. But it ignores ansible.cfg as config file at all, unless set it by ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh Singh, this helped me as I mistakenly gave 777 to the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes you may not change file permission to solve this issue, one example is when you use ntfs format in linux 
TLDR: 
go to the directory where your custom ansible.cfg reside, open a terminal and >

```
export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=./ansible.cfg
```

explanation:
based on ansible official documentations ***[at this page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html)***

Avoiding security risks with ansible.cfg in the current directory
If Ansible were to load ansible.cfg from a world-writable current working directory, it would create a serious security risk. Another user could place their own config file there, designed to make Ansible run malicious code both locally and remotely, possibly with elevated privileges. For this reason, Ansible will not automatically load a config file from the current working directory if the directory is world-writable.

If you depend on using Ansible with a config file in the current working directory, the best way to avoid this problem is to restrict access to your Ansible directories to particular user(s) and/or group(s). If your Ansible directories live on a filesystem which has to emulate Unix permissions, like Vagrant or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), you may, at first, not know how you can fix this as chmod, chown, and chgrp might not work there. In most of those cases, the correct fix is to modify the mount options of the filesystem so the files and directories are readable and writable by the users and groups running Ansible but closed to others. For more details on the correct settings, see:

for Vagrant, the Vagrant documentation covers synced folder permissions.

for WSL, the WSL docs and this Microsoft blog post cover mount options.

**If you absolutely depend on storing your Ansible config in a world-writable current working directory, you can explicitly specify the config file via the ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment variable. Please take appropriate steps to mitigate the security concerns above before doing so.**

Answer (score 1):

For me this was not working....

I needed to unmount it and then mount it again and use another command:

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

Go to the actual folder and:

```
chmod o-w .
```

More Info, [Link1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/) [Link2](https://github.com/trailofbits/algo/issues/1637)